# node js jwt how to pass token to other routes to check logged user information later

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

I'm creating an application learn for my self. So at the moment i need to authenticate an user using with jsonwebtoken and i know how to create a token to authenticate a user. So actually i need to know how can i retrieve logged users's information later by using the token created by the user when logged into the system. i searched everywhere for a good answer but i couldn't find a good answer

```
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

// find the user
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    } else if (user) {

      // check if password matches
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
      } else {

        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'));

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

this is the user login and token creation process

and the below router i need to retrieve all the user information if the user logged into the system and created the token

```
apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  if(!loggedinUser){
    //throw err
}
else {
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.json(users);
   });
  });
}
```

so please help me to understand this and i hope you guys provide me a good answer for this question

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your authorisation token is generated you need to send that token in all requests through client side.
On the the server side you need to implement a authentication middleware in this you will check the authentication token. and process that request further
check this link 
[How to use the middleware to check the authorization before entering each route in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700729/how-to-use-the-middleware-to-check-the-authorization-before-entering-each-route)

Answer (score -1):

Add User login token in to `req.session.token` then check it in jwt middle ware .